# Dagger-2: Field not injected

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

My field for retrofit in this class is never injected into, it is still null when i run my code.

Here is my ServiceClass where I inject retrofit, have my api calls etc. I stripped it down for simplicity:

```
public class ServiceClass{

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    public ServiceClass(){
    }

}
```

My module class for all network related dependencies:

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    Retrofit getRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(Gson gson, HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor){
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.newBuilder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
        return okHttpClient;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    HttpLoggingInterceptor getHttpLoggingInterceptor(){
        return new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    Gson getGson(){
        return new Gson();
    }

}
```

My AppComponent this is my only component class:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(MyApplication myApplication);
        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);

    Retrofit getRetrofit();
}
```

My Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this);
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent(){
        return appComponent;
    }

}
```

I tried to fiddle around the code, I don't seem to manage to get it working properly. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you inject your `ServiceClass` entity?

Comment: You should be injecting it somehow, with your setup, likely `MyApplication.getInstance().getAppComponent().inject(myService)`

Comment: @ror Can you explain a little, please? Where should I do this injection?

Answer (score 1):

Update (previous information still valid) :

I have noticed you incorrectly build your component: you must add `.networkModule(new NetworkModule())` after `DaggerAppComponent.builder()`
Make sure your `private AppComponent appComponent` is initialized too!

---

For field injection (I believe that's what you're after), you can write your constructor like this:

```
public ServiceClass(){
    MyApplication.getInstance().getAppComponent().inject(this)
}
```

Naturally, you should expose your appComponent entity somehow - the above is my guess (to expose appComponent entity via application entity).

PS.: better approach (and more readable too) is to avoid field injection at all and parametrize constructor (however it's not always possible, like for example if you inject into activity).

PSS.: your AppComponent should also have `void inject(ServiceClass value);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't get instance of my application. Do I need Context to be able to access it?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of injecting `retrofit` in `ServiceClass`

1. You have to make a separate `Component` for `ServiceClass` like :-

   ```
   @Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class)
   interface ServiceClassComponent {
      void injectServiceClass(ServiceClass serviceClass);
   }
   ```

Or

2. you can just inject `ServiceClass` into your application component:-

   ```
   void injectServiceClass(ServiceClass serviceClass);
   ```

into your `AppComponent`

The `dependencies` keyword would include all the dependent components into your particular component that you would build.

Then in the constructor of `ServiceClass` you need to build the Component and inject it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Trying this I still have the same problem. It still does not get injected and the field is null, still.

Comment: You need to inject it in the constructor of service class